# Low and crackling sound with Reaktek ALC800

Tags: sound, realtek

I get very low-volume sound in Ubuntu, and when I raise the volume, it's crackling and noisy. In Windows it works fine.

I've got a Realtek ALC800 soundcard, intel ich6 controller.

I have tried everything, from changing the alsamixer configuration to installing the newest alsa drivers, and changing that `alsa modprobe conf` thing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please tag with the version of ubuntu you're using.

Comment: 10.04, soon changing to 10.10

Answer (score 3):

In alsa some cards are not meant to be "maxed out" in volume. I would leave the mixers around 95% or so. If it is still quiet try moving some mixers and not others. This may or may not help you.

Try turning volume down in alsa a bit so it does not crackle and turn the volume up in the pulseaudio mixer to 130% or so. This may change with the alsamixer setting as well though.

You updated alsa drivers correct? Did you use a script method or the Ubuntu Alsa Backports package? I have had good results with the package myself.

If nothing else, report this as a bug. Especially if you figure out a solution. Refer to this documentation for further help: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems

Sorry I could not be of more help, good luck! I know a tiny bit about sound so I can help you look into OSS or something as well (however that road I never went far down). Perhaps if all else fails give a look into this:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSound

Comment: those didn't work, but thank you anyway

Comment: Try this out: Press alt+f2 and run (no quotes) "gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf" Add a new line at the bottom that says (again no quotes) "options snd-hda-intel model=auto" Then reboot.

Comment: Your first alinea is not 100% correct as [changing the volume in PulseAudio and changing the volume in ALSA is directly connected](http://pulseaudio.org/wiki/PulseAudioStoleMyVolumes).  If there is no bug in the ALSA driver, setting the volume to 100% in PulseAudio should set the ALSA device to 0 dB (meaning: no amplification), and there should be no clipping or other artifacts.

Comment: @NightwishFan: auto is the default.  If it's doing something other than auto, it's because a quirk was necessary to make it work properly to start with.

Comment: @alex: try filing a bug `ubuntu-bug -s audio`

Comment: Thanks for the info, it must possibly be needed when you upgrade alsa and the quirk is a hindrance (because it worked before in some situations),

Comment: thanks guys, but it didn't work. i suppose i'll have to report a bug

Comment: i just noticed something. in virtualbox (in ubuntu), the audio info tells me that my soundcard has an intel ich7 controller, but in windows, the everest software (you know, that one that shows hardware info) tells me it's got an ich6. could it be the problem?